# DirectShow+Uncompressed AVI

Tags: c#, directshow, capture

I am trying to capture some stream from a  device and save it to an uncompressed avi file.
I am using C# + DirectShowLib, and the resulting file is always compressed(mjpeg or dv codec).

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you be more specific in which filters, source and decoders you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case the captured stream is already uncompressed AVI you can just make use of the Dump Filter, which writes the stream as is to a file.

Comment: could you give me an example, please?

Comment: What kind of an example? You know about the graph and filter concept in DirectShow? How does your filter graph look like now? I need some more information to give a good answer.

Comment: Not too much. I am trying to achieve this result by using the DxTuner sample application which comes with the DirectShowLib.

Comment: I suggest to read more about the graph and filter concept of DirectShow. You should find lots of resources in the MSDN. Have also a look at the tool GraphEdt where you can construct filter graphs manually. If you can do that, you need to know how to build these graphs automatically using DirectShowLib.